A Dangerous Asian Ruler
What is represented below? The answer is a 9-letter two-word noun.



The dangerous ruler is

 THE KING COBRA

Here is how to complete the grid:

 Firstly place the triangle as represented in the rebus in the tiles of each of the numbers. The circled corner represents the the direction the line should by drawn.
 Then because numbers represent the number of degrees the triangle should be rotated clockwise from its center rotate them accordingly.
 You then draw the lines in directions now that the triangles point to. Then, after a line from one triangle hits another triangle you draw the next line which that new triangle points to and so on so forth. Doing so forms this picture which shows a crown representing a KING and a slinky shape representing a SNAKE beneath it:
 
 And so what could the dangerous asian ruler represented here be other than the KING COBRA!


This is the correct answer! However it would be more clear if you replace each number with a rot13(n pybpxjvfr ebgngrq/aba-ebgngrq gevnatyr. Gura lbh'yy pyrneyl frr gur qverpgvba gurl cbvag gb.) If you could just add an image, that would be great.

Was this more of what you had in mind?

Yes looks good now. Well done!
